# Dict-like Class Argument Expansion

Tags: python, class, dictionary

With Python dicts, you can do the following:

```
thing = {} # or dict()
thing['this'] = "is"
thing["is"] = "sparta"

method(**thing)
```

which the method receives as

```
method(this="is", is="sparta")
```

I have a class very similar to a dict, but with a bunch of extra helper methods. I have defined `__iter__` with it so that I can do `"attr" in thing`. My question is, what "magic method" do I have to define (if there is one) to be able to use `**`?

By the way, I would prefer not to subclass from `dict`.

The way I am making it behave like a `dict` is by manipulating the internal `__dict__`.

Comment: Note that to support `"attr" in thing` you should *not* define `__iter__` but `__contains__`! Using `__iter__` python will provide a default implementation that simply scans all the values, but you can generally do much better then that in a custom implementation.

Comment: I defined `__iter__` with an actual implementation, and it worked fine.

Comment: What I meant is that defining `__iter__` *in order to support `in`* results in an *inefficient* solution. [`__contains__`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__contains__) is the *specific* method that gets called when using `in` and is the one you should use to support that behaviour. If you *also* want to allow `for element in my_object` *then* you should implement `__iter__`.

Comment: @Bakuriu Well, I wanted both. So two birds with one stone.